# How to set a string value to a textView ID?

Tags: android, textview

I have an ID called infoLabel for a textView in my GUI, and I need to be able to set it to the contents of my maze.solve() method, which returns a String. I'm having trouble setting infoLabel to a String because it keeps saying that it's an int and I cannot store String data in an int.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoLabel);
tv.setText(maze.solve());
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to make infoLabel an instance field in the class. I thought that since it was already stored as an ID it didn't need a refrence, but that's all it needed